# Handle transactions on redis queue

Tags: laravel, transactions, redis, queue, laravel-5

I have multiple tasks in a function and i use transaction in function 
I want to use redis queue for this transactional tasks 
For example i have a function like below :

```
 private function  check_destination_delivered($request,$id,$order)
{
    if ($request->get('status') == 'destination_delivered')
    {
      $this->destination_verification($request);
      DB::beginTransaction();
      try
      {
        $this->calculate_credit($id,$order);
        $this->calculate_customer_gift_credit($id,$order);
        DB::commit();
      }
      catch (\Exception $e)
      {
        DB::rollback();
        return $this->respondUnprocessable(1180,'error', $e);
      }
    }
}
```

In this function i want to this line

```
$this->destination_verification($request);
```

Run before transaction begin and after that this lines :

```
    $this->calculate_credit($id,$order);
    $this->calculate_customer_gift_credit($id,$order);
```

Use redis queue to calculate a few hours later and use transaction to every task in there to be done and if some tasks be fail .queue run again until all tasks to be done

Comment: please help friends

Comment: no one........?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix it by put function in queue like below :

```
class CreditJob extends Job implements ShouldQueue
{
use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;

protected $order;
protected $trip;
protected $promotion;
protected $customer;

public function __construct($order,Order $trip,Customer $customer, Promotion $promotion)
{
  $this->order = $order;
  $this->trip = $trip;
  $this->promotion = $promotion;
  $this->customer = $customer;
}

 public function handle()
{
    $retry=0;
    $notDone=TRUE;
    DB::beginTransaction();
    while($notDone && $retry < 5)
    {
      try
      {
          $this->calculate_promotion($this->order);
          $this->calculate_credit($this->order);
          DB::commit();
          $notDone=FALSE;
      }
      catch (\Exception $e)
      {
          DB::rollback();
          $retry++;
          sleep(30);
      }
    }
    if($retry == 5)
    {
        $this->trip->fail_calculate_credit_and_promotion($this->order);
    }
} 

 }
```

If all the tasks not done .in queue loop running again
Is it right?